# Generate unique ID of an object that stays the same across instances

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am generating an object from the database using the following:

```
$game = $this->game_model->get_by('slug', 'some-title');
```

I am also using a cache library in Codeigniter where I write to a cache file by:

```
$this->cache->write($game, $cache);
```

where $game is the object and $cache is an identifier for that object.

I would like to generate a unique ID for this object to use as the cache name. Something like [spl_object_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) but that will stay the same across subsequent instances.

For example if I do:

```
$cache = spl_object_hash($game);

// Cache object
$this->cache->write($game, $cache);
```

It will generate `000000006c5ce27300000000564a8706.cache` as the unique ID, but if I reload the page, I get a different ID, which defeats the purpose of the cache.

How can I get a consistent unique ID for an object?

Comment: Does the object have any unique identifier that is already part of its record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use serialize() and then hash it.

```
$cache = hash('sha1', serialize($game));
```